# Geonode install at Google Cloud Platform

Tags: firewall, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, postgis

I trying to install 'geonode 2.6' at Google Cloud Platform.

Now I already open all my firewall port for geonode server which hosted at Google Cloud Platform.

Even thought, it was not move an inch at final stage which updating geonode IP.

According instruction, at final stage it should be as follow:

geonode-updateip 
at my local virtualbox it works perfectly.
but at Google Cloud Engine, it doesn't work and stop moving at following message...

"Inspecting the available layers in GeoServer ..."

And it doesn't go forward.

My suspect is google cloud platform has one IP at local and another one is external IP.

let say at GCE, has following ip
one for 20.0.0.1
one for loopback
but outside, there is external ip, e.g 300.20.10.1

I try with all
geonode-updateip 20.0.0.1
geonode-updateip 127.0.0.1
geonode-updateip 300.20.10.1

nothing works. and stuck at 
"Inspecting the available layers in GeoServer ..."

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I tested with "n1-standard-1" GCP instance type, I installed geonode 2.6. When I ran "sudo geonode-updateip 127.0.0.1", it ran successfully with the output 'Finished processing 0 layers in 0.0 seconds.' However when I ran sudo geonode-updateip vm-internal-ip , it did not work and later stopped working using the 127.0.0.1 as well and stuck at the Inspecting the available layers in GeoServer. It seems problem with the geoserver configuration file. Here is [another thread](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Installation-Problems-with-version-2-6-on-Ubuntu-16-04-td5323542.html) reporting the same

Comment: hi, I just install on ubuntu 14.0 LTS. it successfully installs both local and external ip at google cloud. maybe the problem is only present in ubuntu 16.04 LTS version.

Comment: I tested with GCP ubuntu 16.04 image: ubuntu-1604-xenial-v20171121a and used this [documentation instructions](http://geonode.org/blog/2017/05/17/geonode-2.6-released/) and it was successful when ran the command: sudo geonode-updateip 127.0.0.1, although it took a while. Try spinning up a new instance using the ubuntu-1604-xenial-v20171121a  image and follow the instructions per the [documentation](http://geonode.org/blog/2017/05/17/geonode-2.6-released/) in sequence.